# How can i add letters that result in another letter in the alphabet?

Tags: java, cryptography

I am trying to create the addition portion of a vigenere cipher and need to add letters in the alphabet together, resulting in another letter from the alphabet. This must be the standard alphabet with not special characters. All 26 letters. 
I can get the number associated with the alphabet number. for example A =0 B=1 ... z=25, So how would i be able to create string full of the letter equivalent of that number?

```
public String encrypt(String orig, String iv, String key) {
    int i, j, result;

    String cipherText = "";
    int b = iv.length();
    //loops through the entire set of chars 
    for (i = 0; i < text.length; i += b) {
        //Splits the char into block the size of the IV block. 
        for (j = 0; j < b; j++) {
            //checks to for first block. If so, begains with iv. 
            if (i == 0) {
                //adding the iv to the block chars 
                char one = text[j], two = iv.charAt(j);
                result = (((iv.charAt(j) - 'a') + (text[j] - 'a')) % 26);
                //prints out test result.
                System.out.println(one + " + " + (iv.charAt(j) - 'a') + "= " + result);
            } else {
                //block chainging, addition, with new key. 
                result = ((key.charAt(j) - 'a') + (text[j + i] - 'a')) % 26;

                //          System.out.println(result);
            }
        }
    }

    return cipherText;
}
```

Comment: suggestion: add more tags to your question, like crypto or such, an better if your title makes it clear that you are talking crypto

Answer (score 0):

I created a new method with a char array and all of the inputs were the alphabet. I called the method with the number in question and returned a char.

```
public char lookup(int num){
    char[] alphabet = {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'};

    return alphabet[num];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the numeric code of `'a'` to `'z'` are consecutive with the `char` type (UTF-16), you could simply use addition:

```
public char lookup(int num) {
    return (char)('a' + num);
}
```

Because `char + int` will result in an `int`, we need to cast the type back to `char`.

Answer (score 0):

Chars can automatically converted to ints. 
For example try this:

```
    final char aChar = 'a';
    char bChar = aChar + 1;
    char uChar = (char) (bChar + 19);
    char qChar = (char) (uChar - 4);

    System.out.println(aChar+" "+ bChar + " " + qChar + " " + uChar);
```